# How to label each equation with some text in a series of equations?

Tags: equations, labels

I was wondering what's the best way to create series of equalities, each of which is labeled on the right with some text, as in this example:

> [image]

I would prefer a version that works both with numbers on the left and without them. I use `\usepackage{gb4e}` to create the same as above, but without explanational labels on the right:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex $a+b$
\ex $=c$
\ex $=1$
\end{exe}
```

Is there a way to add those explanational labels to the right? Or should I use something different than `gb4e`?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{stmaryrd, sfmath, tikz, tikz-cd, qtree, pifont,gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex $a+b$
\ex $=c$
\ex $=1$
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code, that we can play with?

Comment: flalign comes to mind.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, what code do you mean? I've posted the one I use for a series of equalities numbered on the left, but I don't know how to add text-like labels on the right to make it look as the picture I attached.

Comment: A code that we can immediately compile, beginning with `\documentclass`, loading the necessary packages, and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you mean the combilable version of the code I posted, I've just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple-minded but working possibility: `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex $a+b$\hfill(test)
\ex $=c$\hfill(another)
\ex $=1$\hfill(test)
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not this is the ideal solution will depend on the real purpose of this.

Comment: Great! As an addition, if the numbers on the left are not needed, I found that flalign suggested in the comments above works fine with eqno. (I posted the corresponding code in my second question.)